# Audio file formats supporting multiple streams

Tags: audio, file-format

While designing a new feature for a software application that I'm working on, I am attempting to define a table structure for audio files, and I have the following question. Do mp3, m4a, wav, aac, wma, and aiff support multiple streams, and if so how commonly used is the multiple stream feature of each?

Comment: Do you mean multiple streams like stereo or surround sound?

Comment: @mtrw: No those would be channels, I mean streams in a file that contains support for multiple languages for example.  One stream for each language, and each stream has a given number of channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MP3`, `WAV` and AAC(`ADTS` and `ADIF` variants) container formats do not support multiple audio streams. MP4 (.m4a) and ASF (.wma) container formats technically can support multiple audio streams.

Having said that, I have only seen multiple audio streams in `AVI` (DivX files with multiple languages), `VOB`(DVD format with audio in multiple languages) and `MKV`(audio in multiple languages).